# Managing Exceptions with Result in F#

Tags: f#

I have to do some manipulations on some CSV files which are very poorly formatted (several different tables in one file etc).

For this I am using CsvFile.Load and write functions on the Seq of string.

However, to manage exceptions that could arrise from then, I wrote such a function.

```
let tryWithResult f i =
    try
        f i |> Result.Ok
    with
    | e -> ("Exception Raised: " + e.Message + "\n" + e.Source) |> Result.Error
```

Signature:

```
val tryWithResult : f:('a -> 'b) -> i:'a -> Result<'b,string>
```

Do you think it is a proper way to do - in term of F#/FP good practice (and so I can use it within a Railway Oriented Programming https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/)?

I know it is always better to avoid exception treatment but I would like something reasonably "safe" but also not spending hours on it.

Thanks

Comment: it depends how comfortable you are with F# and functional programming. If you are cross training from C# or similar I wouldn't dive into railways and Results until you are comfortable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly reasonable to catch all exceptions an make them into `Result` s, specially if you are doing a self contained solution.

Letting go of exceptions makes sense if 1) you are designing a library for others to use, or 2) your code is part of a larger framework that already handles well unhandled exceptions and logs the errors appropriately.